# Fetch unique values out of 2 common rows

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

Having 2 rows, where one column have unique value and 2 column have non-unique value because of that getting 2 rows, instead I need one row if i have unique value in 1st column

```
91285   X2
87681   X1
91285   C2
87682   X4
```

Expected result

```
91285   X2
87681   X1
87682   X4
```

OR

```
91285   C2
87681   X1
87682   X4
```

I tried with partition over by in oracle getting expected result, but CPU is spiking drastically for huge data. Is there any other way to achieve.

```
SELECT id, type, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
FROM temp;
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `X2` is being retained for `91285` while `C2` is being dropped?

Comment: I have given for an example, either x2 or c2 should retain and one should drop off.

Answer (score 1):

> "CPU is spiking drastically for huge data"

You need to sort the result set to filter out those unwanted rows. That operation costs CPU, and maybe even file I/O if the result set is large enough. The work needs to be done whatever.

Perhaps using an aggregate function will be more efficient:

```
select id
       , max(type) as type
from temp
group by id;
```

MAX() here would give you X2 over C2, as your question asks. You may need a different function if your actual business logic is more sophisticated.

Having a compound index on `temp(id,type)` would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the performance using ROWID if you are not worried about which type to be selected in case of multiple rows with same ID.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_test123 A
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM Table_test123 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID);
```